# How to loop a list on different items inside a function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, loops

I am just getting started on functions in Python. My goal is to loop a list with fruits and for each fruit, print it's letters backwards. When it hits a special character, it will stop and move on to the next fruit. I tried doing this with a loop and adding to the index each time but it would only print the first fruit correctly. If I just put the code for each fruit five times, it works perfectly. Please help me fix the index. Code is below.

```
def reverse(li):
    c = 1
    while c == 1:
        index = 0
        for c in reversed(li[index]):
            if c.isalpha():
                print(c, end="")
                index += 1
            else:
                print()
                index += 1
                break

fruits = ['ap!ple','bana@na','ma%ngo','#orange','pine*apple']
reverse(fruits)
```

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the first part of the word or the second part? ie, if you have `'ap!ple'` are you expecting `'pa'` or `'elp'`?

Comment: Use a for-loop to loop over the strings in the list.   No need for a while loop with indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping through the first element of the list only (`reversed(li[index])`).

```
def reverse(li):
    for word in li:
        for rev_word in reversed(word):
            if rev_word.isalpha():
                print(rev_word, end="")
            else:
                print()
                break

fruits = ['ap!ple','bana@na','ma%ngo','#orange','pine*apple']
reverse(fruits)
```

Output:

```
elp
an
ogn
egnaro
elppa
```

Comment: Good. I would also suggest to rename the variables: a better name for `li` would be `words`. A better name for `ii` would be `word`. Then `for word in words` would be much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

You set `index` to 0, so only the first entry is used. Also, `c` is after the first iteration never equal to `1`, so the while-loop is run only once.

Better create a new string, e.g. with `takewhile` and print it inside a for loop over all words:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def reverse(words):
    for word in words:
        print(''.join(takewhile(str.isalpha, reversed(word))))

fruits = ['ap!ple','bana@na','ma%ngo','#orange','pine*apple']
reverse(fruits)
```